# PowerShell Version on Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget-package

Hello guys I am new at this so please bear with me, I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 on my windows 10 pro machine.

Am having problems with the version of PowerShell. It wants me to use version 3.0 or above but I cant seem to upgrade the Package Manager Console to the latest version.

I do have PowerShell Version 5 installed but somehow the Package Manager Console is refusing to use it. I have done a full uninstall and re-install be hasn’t sort the problem. Can you help please

I Am currently working on [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

when i run this code

```
[Scaffold-DbContext " 'Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True; '" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models]
```

It errors, saying Powershell 3.0 or above is required:

> [The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support PowerShell version 2.0. Upgrade to PowerShell version 3.0 or higher, restart Visual Studio, and try again.]

I run `$PSVersionTable` it returns

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PSVersion  ----------------------------2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions -----------{1.0, 2.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                               
BuildVersion -------------------------6.1.7600.16385                                                                                                                                                                                                           
CLRVersion ------------------------- 4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                          
WSManStackVersion --------------2.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
PSRemotingProtocolVersion-----2.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
SerializationVersion----------------1.1.0.1
```

Thanks

Comment: At what point are you experiencing the probme (ie how can I try to recreate it?) Also, are you receiving any error messages? You should add any of these details to your question

Comment: I have added more info

Comment: Is the above version output when you run `$PSVersionTable` in the nuget console window? If you run that in a normal PowerShell window does it say you have version 5 installed?

Comment: Yes it returns PSVersion : 5.1.14393.576 when $PSVersionTable is ran on a normal PowerSheel window

Comment: You could try re-install NuGet, or uninstall PowerShell tools for VS if you have that and see if it helps

Comment: I have tried re-installing NuGet and uninstalling PowerShell tools for VS but it's still stuck on PowerShell Version 2.0

Comment: NB: If you start powershell as `powershell -version 2` you'll open a regressed instance.  Potentially something in the package manager console's config is causing that version parameter to be applied?  Do you have a NuGet PS profile defined?  i.e. `%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1`

Comment: ps. Looking at the tutorial, it states `Visual Studio 2017` as a prerequisite.

Answer (score 1):

Since you upgraded powershell just reboot your windows machine so that registry updates may be applied, then check if it does not work or you did already then i suspect it requires a older version of powershell that is known to work ok with that version of visual studio, so then you could use a newer version of VS say 2017.